# Re-creating the portals from Across the Spiderverse

Tags: modeling, animation, effects

I'm trying to re-create the portals from Across the Spiderverse. So far all I have are some round circles with a texture that resembles something spacey and portal-ish.
[image]
This one was rendered in Eevee.
[image]
And this was rendered in Cycles. As you can see, they don't look like the movie version. I don't like the carved edges but don't know how to fix it.

I'm aiming for the staticky, inky, hand-drawn effect of the portals in the film.

https://variety.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/SpiderManAcrossTheSpiderVerse_TheSpot_01.jpg?w=1000

[image]

Any ideas on how I would do that?

Comment: Hello could you please show some images or animated gif of the portal you're talking about?

Comment: Sure. The site wouldn't let me upload a photo. Let me grab one.

Comment: or give a link to the video and I'll catch a animated gif

Comment: https://youtu.be/iI7ODpgalnw

Comment: The portals appear around 0:12 seconds.

Comment: I've edited your question, please tell me if this is a good example of the portal you're talking about, maybe do it with the Grease Pencil?

Comment: Yes, that's a good example. Thank you. :) I'll try Grease Pencil. Would I add a brushstroke to the scene to do that?

Comment: Or paint a series of images in a software like Photoshop or Krita and import in Blender as an image sequence or movie, it looks like it has been painted